# Sentry in AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr, apache-sentry

We are planning to migrate from In home Cloudera Cluster to AWS EMR.  The plan is to store data in S3 and process them using EMR Hive.  We have lot of business users who access the data.

Currently we use sentry for authorization What we use similary in AWS EMR. Does EMR support  sentry based authorization for Hive ?

Comment: Did you find answer of your question?

Answer (score 0):

AWS EMR currently does not support Sentry. Although they are testing Ranger with EMR but there is no ETA for official release. You can use the following guide to setup Ranger through a pre-defined template/stack. We were able to get Ranger running just with this one stack.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/implementing-authorization-and-auditing-using-apache-ranger-on-amazon-emr/